# Add count of one factor level within group_by

Tags: r, grouping

I am working on a survey data analysis where I have multiple ovservations in a household and I have both household and individual-level variables. I now want to transform personal level characteristics to a household level, for example how many employed people live in a household.

Minimal Reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble( "id" = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
              "status"= as.factor(c("employed", "employed", "unemployed", "unemployed", "employed", "unemployed", "other")))

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  add_count(status, name = "count_types")
```

The above code produces half of what I want. I want to further create a variable that indicates the number of people of status = employed and assign that to **all** within the same ID. I tried a case_when chain but it produced NA instead of 0s for group 2 where there is no "employed" individual, and only worked if employed is present and the first row within each group.

Thanks for your suggestions, preferable tidyverse-style.

Comment: you don't need `add_count` : `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(n_employed = sum(status == "employed"))` or use `summarise` instead of `mutate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to compare if `status` is equal to "employed" and sum logical vector:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  add_count(status, name = "count_types") %>%
  mutate(n_employed = sum(status == "employed"))
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I needed! I am still somewhat confused when subsetting within mutating.